# Why would a screen(with touch controls) in a vibrating environment be readable if its refresh rate is dynamically matched with vibrations?

Tags: waves, vibrations

So, I was reading about this Dragon V2 and it has got touch controlled screens, but screen might be unreadable for pilots because of engine vibrations and whatnot. I came across this comment on reddit.

*"I read an article on the SLS/Orion. They had a problem with vibrations making screens unreadable. It would have cost millions of dollars to dampen the pod vibrations so the pilots could read their instruments. Then a scientist realized that if you changed the monitor refresh rate to match the vibrations, the screens looked perfectly clear. The million dollar fix was abandoned for a 10 cent accelerometer that adjusted the refresh rate automatically. I see no reason why spacex couldn't use this solution to make the screens useful in the rigor of flight.*
"

Yeah, so, why does matching refresh rate with vibrations solves this?

Answer (score 3):

It's a form of the [stroboscopic effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stroboscopic_effect).

let's suppose you're trying to look at a light which is vibrating between the two points $A$ and $B$:

[image: Light1]

The rapid vibration blurs the light out into a line so you can't see it clearly. However suppose we turn the light on and off in time with the vibrations so it's on when it's near point $B$ and off everywhere else:

[image: Light2]

You can only see the light when it's on, so now you see the light (reasonably) clearly at point $B$ even though it's still vibrating around.

The trouble is that this only works when the vibration is dominated by a single frequency and a single direction. If the light is randomly vibrating around the stroboscopic trick won't work because there's no way of predicting the light's position at any particular time.